# Is there a limit to the number of routes?

Tags: javascript, express, routes, sequelize.js, pg

Here's my issue with Express.Router. I need these 4 routes to work at the same endpoint "/pets/...":

```
petRouter.get("/", petController.getAll);
petRouter.get("/:id", petController.getPetById);
petRouter.get("/mypets", verifyToken, petController.getAllUserAdoptions);
petRouter.get("/myadoptions", verifyToken, petController.getAllUserAdoptions);
```

But whats going on is that I can't use the second one ("/:id") together with the rest. It keeps breaking the server and it gives me this error:

```
    return new sequelizeErrors.DatabaseError(err);
                   ^
    DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]: invalid input syntax for type integer: "mypets" 
     ...
```

And when I use them independently all of them work just fine. Is there any kind of limitation that I'm unaware of?

Comment: `petRouter.get("/:id", petController.getPetById);` is a wildcard route that matches EVERYTHIG at the top level.  Thus no top level routes after it will ever get a chance to match an incoming request.  In general, it's a bad design idea to use a top level wildcard route because that restricts you from using things in your website such as `/contacts` or `/help` in the future.  If the actual `id` value is only digits, then you can use a regex that only matches a top level path with all digits instead and it won't conflict with other top level routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request `GET /pets/mypets` matches both the second and the third route. In the second route, this leads to `req.params.id = "mypets"`, but `petController.getPetById` probably assumes that this is an integer. Hence the error that you observed.

Comment: Humm, I'm not sure why that happened. But I switched the order of the routes, and placed the "/:id" at the bottom, and It worked just fine. Since I'm using typescript, is there a better solution? Or this is It?

Comment: If the `/mypets` route does not call `next()`, that is fine. The `/:id` route will then only be called for `GET /pets/something other than mypets`.